# RegEx search for word then match after a dash

Tags: c#, regex

This is my data

```
When: 1300 - 1500 Apr 16
```

I would like to extract everything starting from the second time interval from the when line.

```
1500 Apr 16
```

I have tried the following `(?<=When:\s)|(\d+)[^-]*$` it works when i try it online however when I run it fails. I'm sure there is an easier way but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You could get it with 2 splits. A regex? `@"-\s*(\d+)"` -> `.Groups[1].Value`.

Comment: Not sure why you used an 'or' in the match pattern.  It looks like your regex was attempting to get the first number, not the 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following regex:

```
When:.+(?<=- )(\d+)
```

Your desired content will be in 2nd group.

Example:

```
var data = "When: 1300 - 1500 Apr 2016";

var match = Regex.Match(data, @"When:.+(?<=- )(\d+)");
Console.WriteLine(match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : data)
```

This will print `1500` on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to just get the number after the hyphen and optional space(s), use

```
var inp1 = "When: 1300 - 1500 Apr 2016";
var m1 = Regex.Match(inp1, @"-\s*(\d+)");
Console.WriteLine(m1.Success ? m1.Groups[1].Value : string.Empty);
// => 1500
```

Or if you just plan to get the second integer from the string, use

```
var result = inp1.Split(new[] { ' ', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) // Split with space and hyphen
           .Where(p => p.All(m => Char.IsDigit(m)))   // Get numeric only parts
           .Skip(1)                                   // Skip the first element
           .Take(1)                                   // Take the second one
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to play around with eg expressions is http://www.regexr.com/

My Regexpression:

```
When:.*- (\d*)
```

The test Cases:

- 1) When: 1300 - 1500 Apr 2016
- 2) 1300 - 1500 Apr 2016
- 3) When:- 1500asdasd
- 4) - 1500 Apr 2016
- 5) When:- 1500
- 6) when:- 1500

1,3,5 Capture 1500

EDIT: Reason Comment by  Wiktor Stribiżew

To account for extra - in the text the first search should be nongreedy like this

```
 When:.*?- (\d*)
```

The Problem here is ofcourse that if there are dashes BEFORE it will also cause problems.
Both Solutions should work for your specific pattern

This one would expect one number a space a dash and a second number .. the second number would be captured here

```
When:.*?\d\b.*?- (\d*)
```

Comment: Playing around with regex is good, but doing that with understanding what you are doing is even better :) http://www.regexr.com/ only supports JavaScript regex syntax. Do you know your expression will fetch the empty string after the last `-` in the string, e.g. [with this string](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=When%3a.*-+(%5cd*)&i=When%3a+1200+-+1500+more+text+-+No+more)?

Comment: you are indeed correct... i was too focused on the case above and didnt include this in my thinking the correct way is to make the first .* nongreed with a ? ==> When:.*?- (\d*)

Comment: Good reasoning. Still `\d*` can match an empty string.